# How to cache filtered out elements to prevent re-rendering inside a v-for?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, v-for

I’ve been working on a Vue.js application that manages user’s notes and allows to easily look them up by title, tags, etc. So the primary view of a logged-in user is a list view of `Card` components. I’m using `v-laz`y and `group-transition` components to enhance usability. Everything works fine, but…

When the set of notes becomes larger (100+ `Card`s), one can notice (especially on mobile devices) that filtering slows down. After some debugging I found that the filtering calculations are not the heavy part but the re-rendering of filtered components is the real problem.
Let’s say, with the following scenario:

- there's a list of 150 `Card` components
- the user scrolled down to the end of the page, so that 150 `Card`s are in fact rendered and one of them contains tag: **tag-1**
- if the user clicks on **tag-1**, 149 `Card`s get filered out, the 1 result
  remains Vvue debug tool shows that 149 `Card` components get destroyed as the computed method `visibleCards` contains only one element)
- if the user unclicks the **tag-1**, all 149 `Card`s are re-rendered again
  (Vue debug tool shows that 149 `Card`s are fully re-created again)

Below, there’s the meat of my `Card` list displaying view:

```html
   <v-row justify="center" dense class="px-sm-2">
      <transition-group
        name="list"
        tag="div"
        class="cardListTransition col-12 pa-0"
      >
        <v-row
          :id="'columnid-' + index"
          v-for="(card, index) in visibleCards"
          :key="card.id + ':' + card.created"
          justify="center"
          class="snipSingleRow"
        >
          <v-col lg="10" xl="8" class="pt-0 mb-lg-4 mb-xl-4">
            <v-sheet min-height="50" class="fill-height" color="transparent">
              <!-- 'threshold: indicates at what percentage of the target's visibility -->
              <!-- the observer's callback should be executed. -->
              <v-lazy
                v-model="card.active"
                :options="{
                  threshold: 0.8,
                }"
                class="fill-height"
                transition="list"
              >
                <Card :card="card" />
              </v-lazy>
            </v-sheet>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </transition-group>
    </v-row>
```

where: `visibleCards` is a result of a computed method inside of which filtering occurs.

**Is there any way** - I’ve experimented with `v-once` or `keep-alive`, etc. with no help - **to save / cache the filtered out components to prevent them from re-rendering once the filters are cleared?**

PS.
Stripping down the list i.e. removing `v-lazy` or `group-transition` doesn’t solve the problem.

I’d appreciate any help / suggestions or further reading on how to solve my problem.

Comment: I'm just thinking out of box:
You can use `v-show` (or manual way to hide component) based on one new property on each card in visibleCards.
So when user clicks on one card, that item gets `.visible` set to `true`, but other cards/items in array get `false`. Ofc, `visibleCards` contains all cards, but only visible items have `.visible` set to `true`.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion works nicely! However, now I'm facing a problem with transitioning of elements. When items are filtered out, their `v-show=false` . But items that take their place aren't transitioning - they're jumping immediately after leave transition ends. I'm aware that on `leav-active` transition I need to set `position=absolute` but in that case the moment the filtered-out elements start leaving, they are collapsed into the same place - to list parent container with `position=relative`. Do you know how to overcome this limitation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/52901934/2948850